# Simple ASIHTTPRequest-based function seems to hang at upload

Tags: objective-c, asihttprequest

I've recently started trying to implement HTTP upload support to a program, but I've been having some difficulty doing so. This is the first time I've ever used objective-c (although I have a C background), so I'm still very new to the language. I've been trying to get it to work using the HTTPRequest library, but haven't been able to get anything to start working. It's a fairly large program (2500~ lines) so I won't paste it here. I'll just paste the function itself here.

```
- (void)Upload2HTTP2:(NSString *)ZipPath
{
        [self UpdateProgressBar:@"Upload2HTTP opening Connection to Website..."];
        NSLog(@"Upload2HTTP called\n");

        //URL to be used to upload
        NSURL *url =  [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ftp.website.com"];
        NSLog(@"Upload2HTTP -%@\n",url);

        //Creates the new ASIFormDataRequest object to do the uploading
        //Uses the ASIHTTPRequest and ASIFormDataRequest libraries
        // http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ for more information
        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request addRequestHeader:@"Referer" value:@"http://ftp.website.com"];

        //Sets the authentication information
        //This should have already been retrieved in RetrieveFromBrowser
        [request setUsername:RespUID];
        [request setPassword:RespPWD];

        //Sets the file to be uploaded
        [request setFile:ZipPath forKey:@"Customer Upload"];

        //Starts the transfer?
        [request startAsynchronous];


}
```

ZipPath, RespUID, and RespPWD are all set in another area of the program. Basically, I've got the username/PW for the HTTP authentication, and the path to the file I want to upload, but I've very little experience with the language and this library, so I'm a bit lost. I can't give any specific errors or reasons as to why it hangs, I just know that after I click upload in the program, it runs through this function, and the program hangs trying to upload the file. Is there anything I'm missing or doing wrong in this function? I'd really appreciate any help you guys could lend.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASIHTTPRequest's asynchronous networking takes advantage of the [delegate design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern). Setting the request's `delegate` property to `self`, having that class adhere to the `ASIHTTPRequestDelegate` protocol, and implementing `- (void)requestDidFinish:` and `- (void)requestdidFail:` should give you callbacks for finish and failure. Quick example:

```
- (void)Upload2HTTP2:(NSString *)ZipPath
{
   ...
   request.delegate = self;
   [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestDidFinish:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSLog(@"Success! Do stuff here with [request responseData] or [request responseString]");
}

- (void)requestDidFail:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSLog(@"Failure! Check out [request error] for details");
}
```

Comment: So, after adding these two functions and the delegate line, one of them will be called after [request startAsynchronous] is called and finished to indicate whether it was successful or failed? Also, if it's successful, is there anything I need to do to complete the upload, or is everything finished afterwards? Do I necessarily have to do anything with [request responseData] as your function states?

Comment: No, not unless whatever you're POSTing to returns data. After the request returns successfully your upload will have completed. If you want to dig deeper into ASIHTTPRequest and the delegate callbacks you get, check out the [documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)

Comment: Feel free to mark this answer as correct if it's solved your problem.

Comment: I'm still having problems, but I think the problem might be on the server's side which is relatively out of my hands. I'll tinker some more, and if nothing else, post again. Thank-you for your help in debugging stuff though, kevboh.

Comment: No problem. Comment here if you need any more help with clientside stuff.